# Wrap text in dataframe in R- or in output cell to Word

Tags: r, ms-word, export, dataframe

I am working in R, trying to export a dataframe to MS Word.  I am using R2wd and would like a dataframe to export to MSWORD, and wrap a long string of text within a cell.  Is that even possible?

Bare minimum at least pass a command from R to set the height of each row to fit the contents of the cell...

I don't see any demos or documentation but surely somebody must need to do that sometimes!

Comment: Are you using the wdTable function to write the dataframe into a table?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but you could export the data.frame to a .Rnw file with `xtable`, process it with `Sweave`, and then run the .tex file through latex2rtf. Unfortunately, latex2rtf does not format tables nicely . . .

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with the [odfWeave](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/odfWeave/index.html) package, which is similar to Sweave, except for you can make dynamic odt (Open Document Format) documents. Well, the package does not generates a doc or docx file, but the odt can be opened without problem in the newer versions of MS Office (2007 and above), and in OpenOffice - so might work for you.

The main advantage of the package is that you can define the styles of the table (header or every cell of the table) to your taste. See the examples in the package's archive for further information.